# Development questions regarding debugging and control flow

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

I'm looking for a better understanding of how the flow of the code works. I'm running `bitcoind -regtest` in one terminal window, and in the other I'm using `bitcoin-cli regtest generate` to create blocks. What I'm having trouble with is understanding exactly what is happening in the code when I'm creating blocks.

My assumption was that blockencodings.cpp was used for that, so I put a print statement in it, but nothing ever prints to the console. Is there some issue with printing to the console when regtesting? Or am I not understanding the control flow here. Just looking for some help understanding either debugging, or the chain of functions when generating a block.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at `miner.cpp`, and perhaps at `rpc/mining.cpp` for the `generate` function that's exposed to RPC.

`blockencodings.cpp` is pretty much only used for the compact blocks P2P format specified by BIP152, and has nothing to do with normal block generation.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the tip. if I'm looking to try out a modification to the block header, is the relevant code in block.cpp and block.h?

Comment: primitives/block.h

Comment: Hmm for some reason the print statements in block.h aren't working. I put one into the CBlockHeader definition thinking it would trigger when I generated a block, but I can't see it in my bitcoind console.